# Keeping Program alive after manual close and start from /Applications

Tags: macos, plist, launchctl

I have written a plist file. The intention is to keep the program alive which is working fine. The problem that I discover is the following. 
If I close the app and start it from the /Applications folder, the helper.plist which I created is not valid for it anymore.
Now I know I can run a script that unloads and loads launchtctl. But this starts my program for a second time with the bundleId of the helper.

Is there any way to reattach the program to the helper if I close the app manually or is this not possible? 
Or would I have to code a wrapper app that only runs the script and has the real program in it's sources?
Is there maybe a smarter solution how this can easily be done? I attached the plist below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com   
/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.test.helper</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a wrapper function that has no other function than to start the Program if it is not running.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    print("starting app")
    //check if application is running. if so terminate
    let apps = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications
    for app in apps{
        if let bundle = app.bundleIdentifier{
            if(bundle.hasPrefix("com.CostumApp.main")){
                print("already running")
                //activating gui
                showFront()
                NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
            }
        }
    }
    //checks if the plist file exists and start reset deamon
    let daemon = checkDeamon()
    if(daemon){
        let helper = getUserLibrary() + "/LaunchAgents/com.CostumApp.helper.plist"
        callShell("/bin/launchctl", arguments: ["unload","-w",helper])
        callShell("/bin/launchctl", arguments: ["load","-w",helper])
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }else{
        print("no helper file")
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }
}
```